# SVN ancestrally related error on a single directory

Tags: svn, merge, ancestor

I'm working on a branch and I want to merge my changes on another branch. Both branches were created from trunk.

In the project there is a root folder (from which I created the branches) and inside that there are many sub-directories.

```
root
|__subDirA
|__subDirB
|__subDirC
```

I'm merging the sub-directories one by one in order to simplify conflicts management, I'm able to merge all of them except one that generates error:

```
E195016: "must be ancestrally related"
```

I tried with `--ignore-ancestry` but I get the error:

```
E200004: Cannot merge automatically while ignoring mergeinfo
```

Actually I don't know hot to solve the issue, it looks strange to me that only one of those sub-directories returns me the error when all of them were created simultaneously.

Comment: If all else fails you could just do it manually. Imagine what the machine would do (or even better what you would like it to do) and do it yourself.